# Ruby vs Java and the bottleneck

Tags: java, ruby, database, web-applications

I want to create a new web billing application, the most intensive task for the app I guess it will be converting invoices (if the user wants to) to PDF and that can probably be done by an external server, the rest is just insert and selects of pure text data to/from a PostgreSQL DB, this app will need to scale to 10,000 users.

My question is, will I hit a language performance implementation issue first (Java-JVM vs Ruby-default-implementation) or in this case does performance really gets hit first by other issue like I/O, database, etc... ? so that ruby vs java performance won't matter in this case.

Comment: Past the other problems you mentioned the implementation and framework will matter more than the language itself. You can have a very fast language but sink it with a heavy and not adapted framework. Both language are used in very fast web applications.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you'll be bound by database and IO performance. Java and Ruby are widely used and I've never seen the language *itself* be an issue. The PDF conversion may be CPU intensive, but:

1. I can't believe you'd be doing this all the time
2. it's the sort of thing that can easily be offloaded to another server and performed in parallel

As ever, *premature optimisation is the root of all evil*. I would knock together a prototype and try and identify any particular issues up front with the parts of the solution that cause you concern (e.g. PDFs)

Comment: Choosing the language is important and a hard choice to reverse, I don't think this could be seen as "premature" (even if performances aren't the first criteria to consider).

Comment: Whilst I understand where you're coming from, I do think in this instance that it won't be the major issue.

Comment: Like Brian said, the language itself almost certainly won't be the bottleneck on performance. What it will affect is development time, so you should go with whatever language/framework you're most comfortable with.

Comment: Brian - by offloaded you mean to another server?